# Serial monitor, DataReceived handler misunderstanding C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm developing a serial monitor for my application in WPF, programming in C#.
I have trouble managing the DataReceived event, because I want a real time monitor like HyperTerminal or TeraTerm for example (I'm not using them because I want my terminal to be a part of an ethernet communication tool, which I already developed using winPcap).

I have to read some data from my microcontroller, display it on the textBox (It just prints a menu and the list of commands available) and when it finishes the loading sequence I would like to interact with it, nothing special, just send a "flash-" command to program the fpga of the board.

My application goes in exception when I try to update the textbox.text with the data received. I tried to search everywhere but despite a lot of examples, I didn't catch something which is explaining the code properly.

Here is the code, thanks in advance

```
    namespace WpfApplication1 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SerialMonitor.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SerialMonitor : Window {
        
        //VARIABLES
        public SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();

        public SerialMonitor() {
            //initialization
            InitializeComponent();
            scanPorts();
           
        }

        
        
        private void scanPorts() {
            textBoxIndata.Clear();
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string port in ports) {
                comboBoxPorts.Items.Add(port);
            }
        }
              
      

        private void openComBtn_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e) {

            comPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            comPort.DataBits = 8;
            comPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            comPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            if (comboBoxPorts.SelectedItem != null && comboBoxPorts.SelectedItem != null) {

                comPort.PortName = comboBoxPorts.SelectedItem.ToString();
                comPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxBaud.Text);

                try {
                    //Open port and add the event handler on datareceived
                    comPort.Open();                 
                    comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());                    
                }              
            }
            if (comPort.IsOpen) {
                label1.Content = "COM PORT OPEN";              
            }
        }


        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
            
        }


        //function to update the textBox, didn't manage to get it working
        private void updateUI (string s) {

        }



        //CLOSE AND EXIT BUTTONS
        private void closeComBtn_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (comPort.IsOpen) {
                comPort.Close();
                label1.Content = "COM PORT CLOSED";
            }
        }

        private void exitBtn_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (comPort.IsOpen) {
                comPort.Close();
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I got now the problem that when I send my command using **SerialPort.Write(string cmd)**, I can't read back the answer...

EDIT: Fixed everything, I will post the code if anyone is interested in programming a tool like this one

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: This was the DataReceivedHandler


private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
            string inData = comPort.ReadExisting();
            textBoxIndata.AppendText(inData);
        } 


but it gave me a Thread conflict

Comment: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataReceived` event returns on another/secondary thread, which means you will have to marshal back to the UI thread to update your `TextBox`

[SerialPort.DataReceived Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is
>   received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a
>   secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some
>   elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a
>   threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main
>   Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do
>   the work on the proper thread.

You can use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher.Invoke Method` to marshal back to the main thread

**Exmaple**

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* Your code here */ }));
```

or

```
someControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* Your code here */ }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got now the problem that when i send my command using **SerialPort.Write(string cmd)**, I can't read back the answer...

Comment: Can you show code for this? I don't see the Write command in the sample given.

Comment: After you use the SerialPort.Write command, are you at least waiting until the response is received?

Comment: Fixed this, I had to set up the port properly, i will post the code if anyone is interest in a tool very similar to this one :)

Comment: I would be interested in seeing your solution but more importantly, I think it would be helpful to others who find this topic in a search and would like to know the answer.